# site not working with url www

Tags: url, .htaccess, url-rewriting

hello im having problem with my site when i type `http://example.com` it works fine but when i type `http://www.example.com` it displays page cannot be found ,

what is the problem i couldnot find , i tried .htaccess redirection also

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it is not working

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should use example.com, or the .example TLD for sample URLs - this guarantees you won't actually end up putting someone else's URL in your examples

Comment: @Gareth - Why didn't you just edit it

Comment: This is a question for servervault.com

Answer (score 3):

If you're redirecting to a different website you have to specify 'http://' at the front, otherwise Apache it will interpret it as a file on the server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the alias for www set in the apache vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *>
..
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also remember to restart Apache after each change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up DNS aliases for both adresses? Do they point to the same IP? Depending on your ISP it may take some time before any changes work for you.